# How to make pagination after merge two collections?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I use the standart method for pagination:

```
$ann = Ann::get()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate($limit);
```

After I do merge `$ann` with another collection:

```
$ann = $ann->merge($ann_subscribed);
            $ann = $ann->all();
```

In result I get `$ann = $ann->all();` without pagination

Comment: That after  to use render()

Comment: There is soution, but it does not work winth render: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30421846/7505394

Answer (score 1):

1- add this to boot function in \app\Providers\AppServiceProvider

```
 /**
         * Paginate a standard Laravel Collection.
         *
         * @param int $perPage
         * @param int $total
         * @param int $page
         * @param string $pageName
         * @return array
         */
        Collection::macro('paginate', function($perPage, $total = null, $page = null, $pageName = 'page') {
            $page = $page ?: LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);
            return new LengthAwarePaginator(
                $this->forPage($page, $perPage),
                $total ?: $this->count(),
                $perPage,
                $page,
                [
                    'path' => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
                    'pageName' => $pageName,
                ]
            );
        });
```

2-From hereafter for all collection you can paginate like this

```
$ann = Ann::orderByRaw('id','DESC')->get();
$ann_merged = $ann->merge($ann_subscribed);
$ann_merged ->paginate(5);
```