# Laravel: Paginate on a merged collection?

Tags: laravel, pagination

I have merged a collection and now I want to be able to paginate it.  I've read [this stackoverflow answer on forPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420505/how-can-i-paginate-a-merged-collection-in-laravel-5) but I don't quite understand how to apply it. Can someone please help clarify? Thanks!

**In my Controller:**

```
$lofilter = request('locationfilter');

$mypostings = Postings::where('location', 'LIKE', '%'. $lofilter .'%')->get();
$otherpostings = Postings::where('location', 'NOT LIKE', '%'. $lofilter .'%')->get();

$postings = $mypostings->merge($otherpostings)->paginate(20);
```

Comment: those aren't really the queries ran, right?

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: because why would you run those 2 queries

Comment: I have a dataset of apartment listings, and I want let users sort it/'filter' by selected locations. So for example if I filter by NY, I want to show all NY listings first, but then below that want to still be able to show everything else. Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: I think you should use CASE Syntax in ORDER BY clause.

Comment: for paginate merged collection see this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56142421/6901246

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in the link that you've shared. In your code `$postings` is a collection and collection does not have `paginate()` method. Instead use the [`forPage()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-forpage) method as stated in the link

```
$postings = $mypostings->merge($otherpostings);
$links = $postings->forPage(1, 20);
```

The first parameter is the page number and the second parameter is the number of items you'd want to display per page. The documentation was pretty self-explanatory though!

UDPATE:

You need to paginate it manually, you could do this in your view (Pseudo Code)

```
{{ $totalPages = count($postings) }}

@foreach ($links as $link)
/* Display the links */
@endforeach

/* Create Pagination Links */
@for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++)
Create the links
@endfor
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent of links() that I can use in the view when I use forPage?

Comment: `$links` is just a variable, use whatever name that is relevant to your application

Comment: Oh sorry I meant: I am trying to do the equivalent of  {{ $postings->links() }} in my view to show the page number and page links, but since I am not using paginate function it says the "links method does not exist". How do I display this in the view?

Comment: Please check the update in answer, though not tested