# Laravel collection always returns an object instead of an array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I have a news page which is being loaded by Vue and Vue Isotope. Vue isotope requires that my data is an array so that I can append more articles to the isotope when the user clicks the "Load more" button. The way this works is, when the user clicks "load more", using Laravel's pagination function, I can simply append the next load of articles to my existing array of articles in my Vue instance.

The issue I am having is that my Laravel collection always returns an object instead of an array, even when I use `toArray()`.

If I load my articles straight from eloquent using `get()`, this works fine and is an array, however because I need to merge multiple eloquent queries together, I am forced to use a collection and `merge()` to merge 4 eloquent queries into one large collection. This is what I believe is forcing the collection to always return as an object.

Below is my function from the controller:

```
public function apiIndex()
{
    $articles = Article::latest('featuredArticle')->latest()->published()->get();
    $twitterPosts = TwitterPost::where('published', 'published')->get();
    $facebookPosts = FacebookPost::where('published', 'published')->get();
    $vimeoPosts = VimeoPost::where('published', 'published')->get();

    $articles->map(function ($post) {
        $post['type'] = 'Article';
        return $post;
    });

    $twitterPosts->map(function ($post) {
        $post['type'] = 'Twitter';
        return $post;
    });

    $facebookPosts->map(function ($post) {
        $post['type'] = 'Facebook';
        return $post;
    });

    $vimeoPosts->map(function ($post) {
        $post['type'] = 'Vimeo';
        return $post;
    });

    $allPosts = collect();

    $allPosts = $allPosts->merge($articles);
    $allPosts = $allPosts->merge($twitterPosts);
    $allPosts = $allPosts->merge($facebookPosts);
    $allPosts = $allPosts->merge($vimeoPosts);

    $allPosts = $allPosts->sortByDesc('created_at')->paginate(15);

    return response()->json($allPosts);

}
```

The closest I have been able to get is by adding `->values()` to the end of `$allPosts` however this removes the pagination link for the next page and only retrieves the actual posts so I cannot use this.

Here is a small snippet for retrieving the initial `$allPosts` data into Vue

```
    mounted () {
        axios.get(this.page)
        .then(response => ([
            this.list = response.data.data,
            this.page = response.data.next_page_url
        ]))
    },
```

Here is a snippet of what method is called when the user clicks the "Load more" button

```
        loadMore: function() {
            axios.get(this.page)
            .then(response => ([
                this.paginatedList = response.data.data,
                this.list.push(this.list, this.paginatedList),
                this.page = response.data.next_page_url
            ]))
        },
```

Because the response is an object, using `this.list.push()` does not work and throws an error because `this.list` should be an array.

Additionally, here is a snippet of my Vue data object

```
        data: {
            page: "{{route('api-news')}}",
            list: [ 

            ],
            paginatedList: [

            ],
},
```

Image of my list object (where list should be an array instead):

[image]

How would I be able to force `$allPosts` to return as an array?

Comment: could you share a snippet of `list` content?

Comment: try `$allPosts->toArray()`

Comment: @adam I have tried this, no difference.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Have edited the post to attach the image. As you can see list is an object but it needs to be an array. A note though, the items inside `list` are fine as objects, however `list` itself needs to be an array.

Comment: list is an object because you have a key of `list`. Remove `list` as a key and you will have a 0 based indexed array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would try adding a call to `values()` *before* the `paginate()` instead of after.

```
$allPosts = $allPosts->sortByDesc('created_at')->values()->paginate(15);
return response()->json($allPosts);
```

The way Vue determines whether an array is treated as an array vs an object is by looking at the keys: if they are numeric, zero-indexed and sequential, it will treat it an array, otherwise, it treats it as an object.

In your case the `sortByDesc()` collection method maintains the original keys so Vue sees non-sequential keys and handles it as an object. By running your sorted collection through `values()` you should get a correctly indexed collection to pass to Vue.

**Update:**

Based on your comment that the above solution is only working for the first page of results but not the others, I suspect that the `paginate()` method is also maintaining the original keys. So the first chunk has keys starting at 0, but the second chunk has keys starting at 15. You may need to override that so that each chunk gets re-indexed to 0.

You may also be able to do this in your Vue code before pushing the results into your model. Something like `response.data.list.filter(item => item)` might work.

Comment: This almost resolved the issue. The first page is fine and the `data` is returned as an array, however the second page `data` is still returned as an object.

Comment: Are you using a macro or something for the `paginate()` method on your collection? Can you post that code?

Comment: @Gazz I have the same exact problem. And the macro code was from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420505/how-can-i-paginate-a-merged-collection-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 6):

Coming across this issue as well, as @Graeme states, this works on the first page, but not the second. In the end I ended up manually overriding the items in the `LengthAwarePaginator` and resetting the array indexes.

```
        $collect = $Products->get()->values();
        
        $ProductsPaginated = ProductResource::collection($collect)->paginate(12);
        $items = $ProductsPaginated->items();
        
        $decodeFix = json_decode($ProductsPaginated->toJson());
        $decodeFix->data = array_values($items);

        return json_encode($decodeFix);
```

Comment: I come accross this problem today. The accepted answer (`adding a call to values() before the paginate() instead of after`) was not working for me. But decoding and temporarily store `data` works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```php
$products = Product::where(...)->get()->paginate(25);
$products->setCollection($products->getCollection()->values());
```