# Laravel paginate and Orderby

Tags: laravel

i have problem with pagination using group by

```
$results = AutomationStep::where([
        ['uuid', $uuid],
        ['step' => $step],
        ['status', $status]
    ])->select('custom_field', 'created_at', 'status', 'reason')->groupBy('subscribe_id')->get();
```

i try pagination  but not working

```
$test =  new LengthAwarePaginator($results, count($results), 10, null,
        array('path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()));
```

please help me, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it

```
results = AutomationStep::where([
    ['uuid', $uuid],
    ['step' => $step],
    ['status', $status]
])->select('custom_field', 'created_at', 'status', 'reason')- 
>groupBy('subscribe_id')->paginate(10);
// Note : 10 = Per page number.
```

Comment: done tks i find solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65710480/how-can-i-paginate-laravel-collection

Answer (score 0):

```
    use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
    
    $results = AutomationStep::where([
        ['uuid', $uuid],
        ['step' => $step],
        ['status', $status]
    ])->select('custom_field', 'created_at', 'status', 'reason')->->groupBy('subscribe_id')->get();

    $perPage = 10;
    $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();

    $currentResult = $results->slice(($currentPage * $perPage) - $perPage, $perPage)->values()->all();
    $updateResultn= new LengthAwarePaginator($currentResult , count($results), $perPage);
```

Comment: hi i have try, but add pagination results null, items: [], but use get working

Comment: How many items you have in your `$results`?

Comment: 11, i use get() the result is correct but i use paginate returns null